# ListView issues removing items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am pretty new to Android Development and still learning some of the skills, but am running into issue with a ListView and ArrayAdapter removing an item.  I have been trying tons of examples and reading as much material as I can, but I think I might be missing something.  For the life of me I cannot get it to work in my code.

Any help would be appreciated.  I have included the code here.

```
public class Favourites extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "favourites";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favourites);

    // Test list of strings- eventually to be replaced 
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
              "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
              "Linux", "OS/2" };

    // First paramenter - Context
    // Second parameter - Layout for the row
    // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
    // Forth - the Array of data
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView list = getListView();

    Log.d(TAG,"adapter count: " + adapter.getCount());

    // Define listView Long Click listener
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);                    

            // Remove Item
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Favourites.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove " + item +" (" + position + ")");
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            final String removeItem = item;

            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {        
                // *** Here is where I am experiencing issues ***
                adapter.remove(positionToRemove);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                      "Favourite "+ removeItem +" (" + positionToRemove + ") Removed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
             });
             adb.show();
             // Return true to consume the click event. In this case the
             // onListItemClick listener is not called anymore.  
             return true;
        }
    });

    // Close button
    View butClose = findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    butClose.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Add button
    View butAdd = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    butAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Comment: Just a little re-iteration.  Everything works, with message box popping up on long click, collecting the Item (text) and index of the item and passing this through to the Toast command.  The issue with is assigning the adapter.remove part to work.  And yes, I know that it might ask for a String instead of position.  Assigning the adapter seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not actually delete directly from the adapter. You have to delete from ArrayList first i.e your data.
So, change

```
adapter.remove(positionToRemove);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to

```
values.remove(positionToRemove);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: values is a String[] array, and doesn't have a remove method.  I will try convert it to an ArrayList and see if that works.

Comment: That's it!  I just tried it by creating an ArrayList, populating it with data from the values string and then adding that to the ArrayAdapter instead of the string[].  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Oh it did.  Spent many hours on that one and lots of reading... and the simple fix was converting String[] to ArrayList, then addressing that instead of Adapter.  You truly are a wizard. lol

Comment: always use a ArrayList instead of array if you want your data to be dynamic(i.e performing deletion, addition in run-time). And thanks for the appreciation, I am more famous by that name rather than my real name.

Comment: Being new to Android programming as well as Java, these are the little tricks I need to learn.  Just following other examples etc from this and other sites.  Unfortunately not one mentioned what you just said.  So simple but completely stumps you if you are not aware.

Answer (score 0):

**The code that worked for me is :**

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
 if (idx != 0) 
 { 
 String delete = (String) ((OdrLst.getAdapter()).getItem(idx));
 //Log.d("Itemdeleted",delete); 
 adapter.remove(delete); 
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
 OdrLst.setAdapter(adapter); 
 //Log.d("adapter count after", adapter.getCount() + ""); 
 //Log.d("lv count after", OdrLst.getCount() + ""); 
 } 
}
```

idx it should be your index position.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the item text and item Index perfectly fine.  The Toast is displaying the stuff (item text, index) without issues.  The big issue is how to address the adapter correctly to be able to remove the item in my code.  I have tried: final ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = (ArrayAdapter<String>) parent.getAdapter();  to set a reference to the adapter, but this crashes the app.

Comment: you can do like this way as per my code OdrLst.getAdapter()).getItem(idx); it will assign in string delete. that you will pass in adapter method remove; and change that stat of list by and assign new adapter like adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling `getListAdapter()` where you used the object "adapter". like

```
getListAdapter().remove(positionToRemove);
getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no method 'remove' in the getListAdapter().

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on HTC wildfire and Nexus 7, the `ListView` didn't refresh a screen after removing an item. However some devices don't experience such problem - e.g. there are no problems on Samsung S II

The fix was strange (at least for me), I took out the `background="@android:color/black"` line from the `ListView` in a layout and everything started working fine.